# VBA Excel Automatically Copy & Paste Specific cells based on IF statement

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, vba

The code I have placed below is a combination of what works and what i can't get to work.

The code that is not commented will copy cells to "sheet2" from "sheet1".

What I cannot get to work correctly is the code that I have disabled that would replace my Range Method of coping from "sheet1" to "sheet2".

Also my `If Then` Code is what will some up what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to get the If statement to search all of column A and copy all Cars that are year 1991 to sheet2.

Mind my poor coding skills I'm Doing my best to show & explain so I can be helped.
 
Here is the Sheets 1 & 2

(hxxp://s15.postimg.org/orfw7tlaz/test.jpg)

**OLD CODE**

```
Sub Macro1()

Set a = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set b = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set c = Sheets("Sheet3")

Dim x
Dim z
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

x = x + 1
z = 2


'lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'lastrow = b.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'For i = 2 To lastrow
lastrow = b.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + x

'If a.Cells(i, 1) = “1991” Then


'a.Cells(i, 1).Copy
'erow = b.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'b.Paste Destination:=b.Range.Cells(erow, 4)
Range("A" & z).Copy Destination:=b.Range("D" & lastrow)

'a.Cells(i, 1).Copy
'b.Paste Destination:=b.Range.Cells(erow, 1)
Range("B" & z).Copy Destination:=b.Range("A" & lastrow)


'a.Cells(i, 1).Copy
'b.Paste Destination:=b.Range.Cells(erow, 3)
Range("C" & z).Copy Destination:=b.Range("C" & lastrow)

'a.Cells(i, 1).Copy
'b.Paste Destination:=b.Range(erow, 2)
Range("D" & z).Copy Destination:=b.Range("B" & lastrow)
'End If

'Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit
'b.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

So I added some Lines and Began changing the cell locations to reflect the format I need and now when I run the macro it only copys the very last line from Sheet1 to sheet2. I believe it has to do with the order of the way these cells are.

```
        b.Cells(erow, 1) = a.Cells(i, 1)
        b.Cells(erow, 2) = a.Cells(i, 2)
        b.Cells(erow, 3) = a.Cells(i, 3)
        b.Cells(erow, 4) = a.Cells(i, 4)
```

Changing these back fixes it so it copys all the cells but its not what I'm trying to do.
The Code I'm Trying to run is Below

**NEW CODE Working Thanks to EntryLevel!**

```
Sub TakeTwo()
    Dim a As Worksheet
    Dim b As Worksheet
    Dim c As Worksheet

    Set a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set b = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrowsheet1 As Long
    Dim erow As Long

    lastrowsheet1 = a.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    erow = b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrowsheet1
        If a.Cells(i, 1).Value = "AEM" Then
            b.Cells(erow, 31) = a.Cells(i, 1)  '<------When I modify these
            b.Cells(erow, 6) = a.Cells(i, 4)   '<------The copied cells
            b.Cells(erow, 28) = a.Cells(i, 5)  '<------Don't show up
            b.Cells(erow, 26) = a.Cells(i, 6)  '<------In Sheet2
            b.Cells(erow, 46) = a.Cells(i, 11) '<------Only the last
            b.Cells(erow, 29) = a.Cells(i, 14) '<------Line found Is copied to sheet2
            erow = erow + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    b.Columns.AutoFit
    'b.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

**Now Using Same Working Code** But **Different function Not Working**

```
Sub TakeThree()
    Dim a As Worksheet
    Dim b As Worksheet
    Dim c As Worksheet

    Set a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set b = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrowsheet1 As Long
    Dim erow As Long

    lastrowsheet1 = c.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    erow = b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrowsheet1
        If c.Cells(i, 1).Value = b.Cells(erow, 6).Value Then 'If serial number is found from sheet2 column 6 in sheet3 Column 1
            b.Cells(erow, 8) = c.Cells(i, 2) 'Then copy description from sheet3 cell row to Sheet2 cell row
            erow = erow + 1
            End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    b.Columns.AutoFit
    c.Columns.AutoFit
    'b.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

So I added another For Loop with Dim r and added another Line erow = erow + r & now the code copys the first 2 rows needed but does not continue iterating down the list. which is confusing me. here is the code below i have added.

```
Dim r As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrowsheet1 As Long
Dim erow As Long

lastrowsheet1 = c.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
erow = b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
 For r = 1 To erow
  For i = 2 To lastrowsheet1
  If c.Cells(i, 1) = b.Cells(erow, 6) Then
     b.Cells(erow, 8) = c.Cells(i, 2)
     erow = erow + r
  End If
Debug.Print i
  Next i
  Next r
```

Comment: "cannot get to work correctly" - what does that code do now? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: `except if there is information in the adjacent cells.` - adjacent cells in sheet1 (where the column A = 1991) or sheet2 (where it will be pasted)? and which cells do you consider adjacent (i.e. - which columns?)

Comment: Grade'Eh' Bacon, Right now the code that's enabled only copy's cells from Sheet1 ( A2, B2, C2, D2) Pastes to (D2, A2, C2 B2) when i run the macro again it pastes to (D2+1, A2+1, C2+1 B2+1) ect.<br>
What I would like the code to do is copy all the code in Column A that has Text "1991" to sheet2 (D2, A2, C2 B2)<br> so when I have 1500 rows with "1999 in Column A I won't have to manually copy and paste them to Sheet2.

Comment: So you need to do a loop that iterates through column A and use an if statement to determine if it moves or not. with z = the row number of the cells in column A being tested.

Comment: Scott Holtzman, I removed the adjacent cells sentence because it was confusing the way I wrote it.
Scott Craner, I'm Not sure exactly if a LOOP and IF Statement will do exactly what I'm asking but I'm Open to the idea of it, Also looking at how you use Array's but i don't know if I can get the code to be very dynamic using a Array.

Comment: Updated the Macro code with the help of EntryLevel, But now I face another problem. All the cells are not being copied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement that `I'm trying to get the If statement to search all of column A and copy all Cars that are year 1991 to sheet2`, it seems like `Autofilter` might be an easier solution than looping.  You should be able to use something like this:

```
Sub TestyTestTest()
    Dim lastrowsheet1 As Long
    Dim lastrowsheet2 As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lastrowsheet1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrowsheet1, 4)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1991"
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrowsheet1, 4)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lastrowsheet2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(lastrowsheet2 + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Trying to stick close to your original code, would something like this be more like what you are looking for?

```
Sub TakeTwo()
    Dim a As Worksheet
    Dim b As Worksheet
    Dim c As Worksheet

    Set a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set b = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrowsheet1 As Long
    Dim erow As Long

    lastrowsheet1 = a.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrowsheet1
        If a.Cells(i, 1).Value = 1991 Then
            erow = b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            b.Cells(erow, 1) = a.Cells(i, 1)
            b.Cells(erow, 2) = a.Cells(i, 2)
            b.Cells(erow, 3) = a.Cells(i, 3)
            b.Cells(erow, 4) = a.Cells(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    b.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

**SECOND EDIT - OP's NEW PROBLEM:**

It looks like your data is just pasting over itself because `erow` is defined as the row after the last row in column 1 that is not empty, but you are not actually putting any data into that column, so `erow` isn't moving down to the next line.

Basically, change the column number in this line:

```
erow = b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

The `1` in `b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, 1)` should be changed to a column number that you paste data into every time. Alternatively, you could use `erow` as a counter and increment it manually each time through the loop. In that case move the existing line that defines `erow` up underneath the line that defines `lastrowsheet1` and then put `erow = erow + 1` inside the loop after all the pasting has taken place but before `End if`. If you put it after `End If`, you'll end up with a bunch of blank lines between your data.

Comment: So I understand doing an automatic filter on vba may take the other cars out of sheet1, But the reason I need to use a if statement is because I have to be able to use multiple filters that automatically search and copy selected cells and pasting them into a pre-formatted sheet2.  Sounds silly but I have product listing with 200,000 rows that I need to retrieve information  to paste to selected cells. I didn't put that in the overall question because I already feel like I'm overly complicating the macro. The code I'm trying to get to work is the beginning portion.

Comment: I don't think I understand why a filter with multiple criteria and copying only the remaining visible cells won't work, but I'll accept it and try to edit your original code.  Are the columns on sheet 2 in the same order as the columns on sheet 1?  Or do we need to rearrange the order when we paste the data? Also, what are we trying to do with that `z` variable?

Comment: EntryLevel, The z variable was just me trying to clean things up but ignore that for now, To help you understand the bigger picture for what I'm getting at. If i was to open my product database it has over 154,000 rows & 17 columns wide the formatted sheet2 is in a complete different order and has about 50 columns. In example I need to be able to select the brand I want to copy all the products cells that I need to the proper place in there correct order of Sheet2, Then sheet2 with have the required unique information from the cells of sheet1 & the rest of Sheet2 can be Null.

Comment: To add to making it complicated I have multiple excel sheets i need to source information from automatically using some kind of search Cell for Exact Text string then copy certain cell from pertaining row to one of the 50 columns for the specific product. sounds crazy I know.

Comment: If I disable b.Range("A1").Select then it works exactly like i was orginally asking and the code you put was so simple compared to what I had been trying all day to do Your Awesome!

Comment: What's up with the edits to my answer? It looks like everything after the second code section should have been an edit to the original question.

Comment: I removed those erroneous edits and made new edits that add to my original response and answer the new questions from @Michael M.

Comment: I have changed the placement where erow =.b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).Row to underneath line that defines lastrowsheet1 &  added erow = erow + 1  and I have the exact same output.  Only the very last line from sheet1 is copied to sheet2.

Comment: Can you please update the code in your question to reflect your changes?

Comment: Added the code you said would correct the issue to the orginal fixed code. @EntryLevel

Comment: I am not able to replicate your issue. I reran your new code unmodifed on some test data, and it looks like it is working to me. It copies over the data for each sheet 1 row that has "AEM" in the first column and it places each piece into the specified columns.

Comment: Though I will mention that if you initially define `erow` by going `.End(xlUp)` from the bottom of the first column but don't actually ever put data into the first column, then it will always initially define `erow` as row 2 (assuming you have column headings in row 1).  That means it would start writing the data into row 2 of sheet 2 every time instead of appending the new data at the end of the existing data. You'll probably still want to change that initial `erow` definition to look at a column that has data every time, perhaps column 31 where we know it puts "AEM" every time.

Comment: After trying the fixed code on a different computer and using different test data it worked corrected right away. But then I thought I could use a modified version of the IF Statement to add additional functionality by searching column 1 rows for = to column 6 rows, Then copy description from sheet3 cell row to Sheet2 cell row. The Problem is the code only copy's the very first row to sheet 2 then stops, where the code unmodified return all rows to sheet2 columns.

Comment: Your new outside loop, the one that starts `For r = 1 to erow` is basically saying `For r = 1 to 2` because `erow` is still defined based on the last row in column 1 that has data plus one row. So it probably finds your column header in row 1 then adds 1 to that via `Offset(1,0)` and sets `erow` to 2.  Then it only goes through that outside loop twice so it's stopping before you want it to.

Comment: Can you also please elaborate more regarding what you want this new section of your code to do?  I think there may be other gremlins we need to work out, but I'm getting confused about which sheets and columns we are trying to compare in this new section.

Comment: So I figured by adding another variable and containing the loop inside of a loop it would continue down the sheet3 column,  the purpose of this code is after the code you helped me with macro "TakeTwo" there will be 356 rows of unique texts in column 6 of sheet 2, the code iterates through column 1 of sheet3 once a match is made then in that matching row it takes c.Cells(i, 2) and pastes them to the corresponding row b.Cells(erow,8) then it continues down the entire column of sheet2.

Comment: That sounds like a job for a `VLookup` formula.  Have you tried putting something like `=VLOOKUP($F2,Sheet3!$A:$B,2,0)` into `Cell H2` on `Sheet 2` and copying the formula down that column?

Comment: VLOOKUP function would be great but I need the automated verson by running a macro so it can be ported to click of a button on a UserForm,So Is there a way to use the simple For Loop function to do a Simular to Vlookup?

Comment: We can add that formula in to column 8 of sheet 2 when it initially copies the data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 in the TakeTwo sub. Would that work?

Comment: I added that formula to cell H2 it worked for row 2 but then you have to change $F2 to $F3 for row 3 then $F4 for row 4 ect.. so it would require another variable. Also using the vlookup function kind of mirrors the info from the Cell to the cell with the function without actually coping it?

Comment: If you copy cell F2 and paste it down into the rows below it, it will change the row number in the formula automatically. If we didn't want it to automatically update the row number as you copy it down, we could put a $ in front of the 2 so it would be $F$2 (that isn't what you want, just a side note about how that works).  However, if you'd rather have just the value in there instead of the actual formula, we can have the vba do the same thing and just put the value in there instead of the formula.

Comment: In the `TakeTwo` sub, you could put `b.Cells(erow, 8) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(b.Cells(erow, 6).Value, c.Range("$A:$B"), 2, 0)` right above `erow = erow + 1` if you just want the value in there.

Comment: Or if you want the formula to show in the cell, you could use `b.Cells(erow, 8).Formula = "=VLookup($F" & erow & ", Sheet3!$A:$B,2,0)"` in that same place.

Comment: The first way of using 'VLOOKUP' error's to that line but the 2nd one works correctly. I'm going to try added more to the 'taketwo' sub and see how it works out.

Comment: using `b.Cells(erow, 8).Formula = "=VLookup($F" & erow & ", Sheet3!$A:$B,2,0)"` how do I put a If within the function, So when  Vlookup fails finding erow to display a Generic value  instead of #N/A in the cell?

Comment: Sorry, my grandfather passed away and I haven't been around to see this until now.  If you still need an answer, give `b.Cells(erow, 8).Formula = "=iferror(VLookup($F" & erow & ", Sheet3!$A:$B,2,0)," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"` a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  very sorry to hear that, EntryLevel.  Family comes first.

Comment: So did that work for you or do we still have some kinks to work out?